# Multiple receivers to Azure IoT Hub, How to set Epoch Value of an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, events, iot, epoch, azure-iot-hub

I've got an IoT Hub in **Azure** that I send messages to from my Raspberry Pi. 
A Web Application and an Azure function receives these messages, and it works great while doing it one by one.

**The problem** is that when I try to receive messages with the Web Application and the Azure function at the same time, I get an exception in the Web Application that says that the Epoch Value of another receiver is 12. The other receiver in this case is my Azure Function.

I followed this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gyan/2014/09/02/event-hubs-receiver-epoch/) and as I understood I will have to set the Epoch value of my Azure Function to 0, to enable multiple receivers from the same IoT Hub.

My question is how do I set the Epoch value of an **Azure Function Event Hub Trigger**? Or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Did you try using different consumer groups, one for your Web Application and one for your Azure function?

Comment: Ah, that solved it! Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem, I've posted it as answer so the question will be marked as resolved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have several consuming applications with independent views, you can use Azure IoT Hub consumer groups. They enable multiple consuming applications to each have a separate view of the event stream, and to read the stream independently.